# Can a View Controller inside a PageViewController animate upwards when Swipe Gesture Up is done by the user?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UIPageViewController, with a couple of view controllers inside. It is currently horizontal scrolling and I've added a swipeUp gesture to the view itself.

```
    var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeUpAction))
    swipeUp.direction = .up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
```

I was wondering if it was possible to animate the view controllers inside the PageViewController upwards when this SwipeGestureRecognizer was hit by the user? And after the animation is done, to remove the ViewController from the PageViewController.

Comment: You don't need to add a gesture recognizer, you just need to implement your `UIPageViewController`'s delegate methods in order to be able to swipe.

Comment: I already have it swiping left and right with the delegate method. What I mean is I'd like to have pages be able to swiped up, which then make that view controller disappear from the UIPageViewController altogether as part of the UX functionality to 'select' things from different PageViews. @PabloA.